# Synology Diskstation has two ssh ports after changing standart port on DSM 5

Tags: ssh, nas, port, synology

I was trying to change the standard ssh port on my Diskstation, running DSM 5, by editing those two files:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc.defaults/ssh/sshd_config
```

and uncommenting and changing the line whichs says:

```
#Port 22
```

to

```
Port xxxxx
```

with the result, that after the restart the diskstation was ssh accessible on both ports, 22 and xxxxx. What can I do to permanently disable port 22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which exact version of DSM 5 are you running? From version 5.1-5004 [you can change the SSH port through DSM:](https://www.synology.com/en-global/releaseNote/DS211j)

> Version: 5.1-5004
>
> (...)
>
> 25. **Misc**
>
>     - You can set global firewall rules for all network interfaces.
>     - You can set default permissions for external drives.
>     - You can define each FTP user’s root folder to be a folder other than their home folder.
>     - You can filter Domain Users and Groups by Organizational Unit.
>     - A command-line-based FTP client is built-in for automated tasks.
>     - **You can now customize the SSH port.**
>     - Python core is now built-in.

### To change SSH service port

First go to **Control Panel** > **Terminal & SNMP** > **Terminal**.

> 1. In **Port**, enter a new port number.
> 2. Click **Apply**.

[Synology DSM Help](https://help.synology.com/dsm/?section=DSM&version=5.2&link=AdminCenter%2Fsystem_terminal.html&lang=enu)